# CSS Animate Content

Tags: css, css-animations

**How do I animate text using CSS?**

I'm trying to simply change the letter using purely CSS every second though I haven't done much work with CSS3 Animation. Here is what I've come up with thus far:

```
a:link::after {animation: test 1s linear 1s infinite alternate;}

@keyframes test
{
0% {content: 'a';}
16% {content: 'b';}
32% {content: 'c';}
48% {content: 'd';}
64% {content: 'e';}
80% {content: 'f';}
}
```

---

Since I can not change the `content` property I can probably pull this off with `overflow` and changing the dimensions such as `padding` and `width` somehow...

No JavaScript and definitely no frameworks.

Comment: How exactly do you want to animate it? Fading? Moving in and out? Scaling?

Comment: @nils There are many ways I've considered. Since I can't seem to change the text using `content` I've considered changing the individual letters though at most CSS only providers `:first-letter` access. Using `margin`, `padding`, `position`, `transform` and `transition` are other options I'm messing with. This must be done with a single element though.

Comment: Why do you need to do it with a single element and no javascript? That makes it a lot harder... Can you not even have sub-elements in the parent element?